# Multiple horizontal nested form-rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, forms, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4.0 beta 2 and try to align label and form control horizontal in one line by using `form-row` and `col-*` classes.

Now I'm trying to align two of these `form-row` structs in one line, see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtrzkp1y/1/) (use HD resolution when running). But I don't know why the first input in first row is not vertically aligned with input field of second row. I've struggled for some hours now and using different classes `form-inline`, `row`, and so one and tried to play with margin and padding classes, but no luck.

The DOM cannot be changed, only the classes applied. Who can help me?

Comment: In this case `fieldset` have `min-width: 0;` You shouldn't use `fieldset` element instead of you need to use `div`. Check the fiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/wtrzkp1y/2/. I hope it will work.

Comment: That displays all three fields in one row, that's not what I want, sorry. The left border of first input field in first line has to be vertically aligned to the left border of input field in second line.

Comment: Check now my ans. your issue is fix. https://jsfiddle.net/wtrzkp1y/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your first column additionally has `form-row` on it, creating a row inside another row. There should *never* be a row inside a row; only use columns inside of rows. These rows add additional padding (`15px` for `row`, and `5px` for `form-row`), which interferes with the percentage-based widths and offsets when you nest them.

Instead of nesting your second `label + div` inside of a new `form-row`, you need to take it out of its `form-row`, and place it inside of the `form-row` of the **first** `label + div`. After this, you'll need to adjust the `col-md` counts of both `label+ div` combinations to suit.

I've gone with `2` and `3` respectively, as that comes to a grand total of `10` ((`2` + `3`) + (`2` + `3`)), which equals the total of your second row (`2` + `8`).

I've created a fiddle showcasing this **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/42nonka5/)**, and you can also see this by maximising the snippet below:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-row">
      <label class="col-form-label col-md-2 col-sm-12">LABEL</label>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <label class="col-form-label col-md-2 col-sm-12">LABEL</label>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row mt-2">
      <label class="col-form-label col-md-2 col-sm-12">LABEL</label>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Hope this helps! :)

### CSS Only Solution:

Assuming you **can't** modify the DOM, you can **[always fall back to CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/esnvmnkz/)**:

```css
.form-row.mt-2 {
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .form-row.mt-2>div {
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 13px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-row col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <label class="col-form-label col-md-4 col-sm-12">LABEL</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <label class="col-form-label col-md-4 col-sm-12">LABEL</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row mt-2">
      <label class="col-form-label col-md-2 col-sm-12">LABEL</label>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Though again, the DOM modification would be the more preferable solution :)

Comment: There is no other way than modifying DOM?

Comment: Well you probably *could* use a CSS selector to only target the second box and offset the added padding, though it's probably a 'better' idea to correct the markup if at all possible. I appreciate that might not be possible though, so I'll try to add a CSS-only solution as well :)

Comment: @rabudde -- I've added a CSS solution as well. It will scale so that the boxes align perfectly at any width. Note that you may have to adapt based on how many additional rows you have :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the snippet.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<form class="col-12">
 <div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
       <div class="form-row">
        <label class="col-form-label col-md-4 col-12">LABEL</label>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
       <div class="form-row">
        <label class="col-form-label col-md-4 col-12">LABEL</label>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
       </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-row align-items-center mt-2">
  <label class="col-form-label col-md-2 col-12">LABEL</label>
  <div class="col-md-10 col-12">
   <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use it after `form` `tag`. But rest of the `html` structure with `css` `class` will be same.